# LINQ: When to use 'new' in Select clause?

Tags: linq, select, new-operator

When is it required to use new in the select clause as in the following example? Thanks.

```
var results = from person in people
              select new { FN = person.FirstName, LN = person.LastName };
```

I've searched and partially understand this: "*In the select new, we're creating a new anonymous type with only the properties you need*." But does it mean I can omit new and not get an anonymous type?

To restate my question in another way: is 'new' optional? Is 'new' here similar to C# new where it is not required with value type?

Can I do this?

```
var results = from person in people
              select { FN = person.FirstName, LN = person.LastName };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `new` is not optional if you're selecting "new" objects. (which is what you are doing.  You are creating new objects of an anonymous type with 2 properties `FN` and `LN`)

Simply omitting `new` is a syntax error.

If you have an existing type you would like to use, (say you've defined a `class` `Person` with 2 properties `FN` and `LN`) then you can use that type.  E.g.

```
var results = from person in people
              select new Person { FN = person.FirstName, LN = person.LastName };
```

(assuming Person has a parameterless constructor and `FN` and `LN` are properties with setters)

The only time you can omit `new` is if you are not creating a new object, for instance:

```
var results = from person in people
              select LN = person.LastName;
```

There you are selecting just the `LastName` and the result is an `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 1):

If you are projecting to a *new* type (anonymous class or known class/struct) it is not optional but required.

If you are projecting to an *existing* instance though of course you don't need the `new`, i.e. in your example if you just wanted to project to the first name of each person (to get a string enumeration you could just do:

```
var results = from person in people select person.FirstName
```

So rule of thumb if you are constructing a new type you need new in the projection (`Select`), if you are just selecting something that already exists you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an anonymous type you can instantiate an instance of a named type that takes a Person as an argument or assign values using the object initializer syntax.

Example:

```
var results = from person in people
              select new Report(person);

var results = from person in people
              select new Report() { Customer = person };
```

Edit: Or of course just select a single property from the person object as BrokenGlass pointed out!

Edit: I just re-read your question and wanted to point out that anonymous types in C# are just normal types with the type name generated by the compiler. So yes, you still need to use the new operator because you're creating a new instance of a type. [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)